# Is it possible to use Google Cloud Messaging for my system?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing a client server system. The server is a Java application that runs 24/7 and get information from the web all the time to keep updated. The client is an Android app.

This is the way that the system has to work:

1. The client can register to the server for some information.
2. If the client registers correctly, the app has to run in background 24/7 waiting for server messages.
3. The server has to know the clients registered and send the information to all the registered devices everytime its information is updated.
4. If the client receive information that meets a condition then it stops running in background, unsuscribe to the server and activate an alarm.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to do the communication using Google Cloud Messaging?
2. The way to do the client run in background 24/7 is using android services or am I wrong?

Thanks,

SB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you definitely can and should use GCM, that's why it exists. doing anything else is going to be a lot of work to get right, and is going to be highly inefficient when it comes to network and battery usage,

> http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html